# How to parse json with javascript/jquery if content matches string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I currently have a json file of people taking part in a series of charity events in the following format:

```
[
 {
   "FirstName": "Anushka",
   "Country": "UK",
   "Day": "13/10/2017"
 },
 {
   "FirstName": "Alessandra",
   "Country": "IT",
   "Day": "16/10/2017"
 },
{
   "FirstName": "Clare",
   "Country": "US",
   "Day": "13/10/2017"
 }
]
```

I want to build a simple HTML list using this data, so that under each date, the name and country are displayed like:

```
<div id="13102017">
<h1>13/10/2017</h1>
<div class="col-sm-4"><p>Anushka, UK</p></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><p>Clare, US</p></div>
</div>

<div id="16102017">
<h1>16/10/2017</h1>
<div class="col-sm-4"><p>Alessandra, IT</p></div>
</div>
```

I've new to JSON and so far I have figured out how to get Name and Country onto the page, but I cannot figure out how to use an if statement to only output if date = 13/10/2017 for example.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$.getJSON("URL_HERE", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        $('#13102017').append('<div class="col-sm-4"><p>' + item.FirstName + ", " + item.Country + '</p></div>');
    });
});
});
```

Obviously the above is currently just outputting every single name into the #13102017 section. I know I probably need an IF in there somewhere but I'm otherwise stumped. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: check if item.day === '13/10/2017'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each loop, check first if the date div exists, and if not, create it. Then append the info to that div...

```
$.getJSON("URL_HERE",function(data) {

    $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        var dateId = item.Day.replace(/\//g,'');

        if (!$('div#'+dateId).length)
            $('body').append('<div id="'+dateId+'"><h1>'+item.Day+'</h1></div>');

        $('div#'+dateId).append('<div class="col-sm-4"><p>' + item.FirstName + ", " + item.Country + '</p></div>');
    });
});
```

For array loops, I personally prefer to use `for` (is faster than jquery `each`)...

```
$.getJSON("URL_HERE",function(data) {

    for (var i=0, l=data.length; i<l; i++) {

        var item = data[i],
            dateId = item.Day.replace(/\//g,'');

        if (!$('div#'+dateId).length)
            $('body').append('<div id="'+dateId+'"><h1>'+item.Day+'</h1></div>');

        $('div#'+dateId).append('<div class="col-sm-4"><p>' + item.FirstName + ", " + item.Country + '</p></div>');
    }
});
```

***NOTE***: I'm adding the date div's to the body, just change `$('body')` to the container where you want to put them in your page.

Answer (score 0):

> but I cannot figure out how to use an if statement to only output if
>   date = 13/10/2017

Simply check if `item.Day == "13102017"`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("URL_HERE", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            if ( item.Day == "13102017" )
            {
                var id = item.Day.replace( /\D/g, "" );
                var html = '<div id="' id '">';
                html += '<h1>' + item.Day + '</h1>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-4"><p>' + item.FirstName + '</p></div>';
                html += '<div class="col-sm-4"><p>' + item.Country + '</p></div>';
                html += '</div>';
                $(body).append( html );
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create the whole html and then set it as html.

```js
var data = [{
    "FirstName": "Anushka",
    "Country": "UK",
    "Day": "13/10/2017"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Alessandra",
    "Country": "IT",
    "Day": "16/10/2017"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Clare",
    "Country": "US",
    "Day": "13/10/2017"
  }
];


$(function() {

  // You can have this inside $.getJSON
  var _html = "";
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    _html += '<div id="' + item.Day.replace(/\//g, "") + '">' +
      '<h1>' + item.Day + '</h1>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-4"><p>' + item.FirstName + ", " + item.Country + '</p></div>' +
      '</div>';
  });

  $("#container").html(_html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```